# How to get an attribute name similar to Function.name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My goal is to safely type an attribute, e.g I have an object

```
const identity = {
  address: "Jackie"
};
```

At some point, I will change the `address` key to something else e.g `street_address`.

This is how I currently use it:

```
<input name="address" value={identity.address} />
```

Sometimes I forget to update the `name` attribute to `street_address` as well.

I wish to be able to use something similar to the Function objejct `Function.name`

```
<input name={identity.address.name} value={identity.address} />
```

Comment: What is `identity` in your case? Where is it stored? Is it stored in state?

Comment: @blaumeise20 identity is just a regular Object. I store it e.g in `React.useState<IdentityInterface>()`

Comment: When you change the name of `address`, you will have to change it in `value` too, right?

Comment: @blaumeise20 yes, because I use `handleChange = (event) => {setState({...state, [event.target.name]:event.target.value})`

Comment: Ahh, i understand your use case.

Comment: Why do you want to change the name later?

Comment: @blaumeise20 various reason, one of them are the REST contract changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create a helper function.

Here's the SO's answer:

[nameof keyword in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470025/nameof-keyword-in-typescript)