# How to identify an index signature in an object?

Tags: typescript

I couldn't figure out the correct answer for this typescript question:

Implement `RemoveIndexSignature<T>` , exclude the index signature from object types.

For example:

```
type Foo = {
  [key: string]: any;
  foo(): void;
};

type A = RemoveIndexSignature<Foo>; // expected { foo(): void }

/* _____________ Test Cases _____________ */
import type { Equal, Expect } from "@type-challenges/utils";

type Foo = {
  [key: string]: any;
  foo(): void;
};

type Bar = {
  [key: number]: any;
  bar(): void;
  0: string;
};

const foobar = Symbol("foobar");
type FooBar = {
  [key: symbol]: any;
  [foobar](): void;
};

type Baz = {
  bar(): void;
  baz: string;
};

type cases = [
  Expect<Equal<RemoveIndexSignature<Foo>, { foo(): void }>>,
  Expect<Equal<RemoveIndexSignature<Bar>, { bar(): void; 0: string }>>,
  Expect<Equal<RemoveIndexSignature<FooBar>, { [foobar](): void }>>,
  Expect<Equal<RemoveIndexSignature<Baz>, { bar(): void; baz: string }>>,
];
```

Here is the top voted answer:

```
type RemoveIndexSignature<T, P=PropertyKey> = {
  [K in keyof T as P extends K? never : K extends P ? K : never]: T[K]
}
```

From my understanding, the code above firstly checks if K is an exact match of one of the `PropertyKey`(number | string | symbol) types. If so, exclude it. If not, it further checks if K is a property key. If so, include it. if not, exclude it.

The answer works perfectly, but I don't understand why do we need double extend clauses. If my understanding above is correct, why can't we stop checking once we've known if K is an exact match of one of the `PropertyKey`(number | string | symbol) types? I.e,

```
type RemoveIndexSignature<T, P=PropertyKey> = {
  [K in keyof T as P extends K ? never : K]: T[K]
}
```

However, the solution above doesn't work.

Comment: Is your question "how [can I] identify an index signature" as the title implies? Or is it "why do we need double extend clauses"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove index signature using mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465182/how-to-remove-index-signature-using-mapped-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taking advantage of the fact that any string is assignable to `string`, but not the other way around. You can assign `"foo"` to some context that expects a `string`:

```
let x: string = "foo"; // okay
```

But you can't assign a `string` to something that wants a `"foo"`:

```
let x: "foo" = string; // error!
```

This is because `"foo"` is a subtype of `string` (and `string` is a supertype of `"foo"`).
Therefore, if we want to identify if `K` is a `string` and not a *string literal type*, we need to try to "assign" it to a subtype of `string`. Lucky us, that is what `extends` does.

```
type RemoveIndexSignature<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : K]: T[K];
};
```

If we can assign `string` to `K`, then `K` must be `string` (or some union that includes `string`), so we can ignore it by using `never`.

By extension, if we want to remove index signatures with `number` (or `symbol`?), you would add more checks after the check for `string`¹:

```
type RemoveIndexSignature<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K]: K
};
```

This is really what the top-voted answer is doing. The trick is to use [distributing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to make this more concise. Cleverly using a type parameter defaulting to `PropertyKey`², we can then distribute that type parameter across `... extends K ? never : K`:

```
type RemoveIndexSignature<T, P = PropertyKey> = {
  [K in keyof T as P extends K ? never : K extends P ? K : never]: T[K];
//                 ~~~~~~~~~~~ distribute P
//                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~ into this
};
```

For `K` to be a literal string type, it must fail the check `P extends K` and pass the check `K extends P`, because like I said above, "any string is assignable to `string`, but not the other way around".

```
K in keyof T as P extends K ? never : K extends P ? K : never
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~ any string is assignable to `string`
                ~~~~~~~~~~~ but not the other way around
```

---

¹ This is also what the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956054/18244921) of a related question is doing.

² The type `PropertyKey` is a built-in provided by TypeScript that is equivalent to `string | number | symbol` or `keyof any`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check both ways for an exact match because `P = PropertyKey` could be a *wider* type than `keyof T`. An example to break it down:

```
type RemoveIndexSignature<T, P = PropertyKey> = {
  [K in keyof T as P extends K ? never : K]: T[K];
};

type Result = RemoveIndexSignature<{[x: string]: any}>;
//   ^? type Result = { [x: string]: any }
```

Here you basically check if `P` (`PropertyKey`) is assignable to `K` (`string`). Since `string` is more specific than `PropertyKey` (=`string | number | symbol`) the conditional jumps to the *else* (`:`) and keeps `K` (=the index signature).

Now let's take a look at the other way around. Same situation, one type could be *wider* than the other. Another example:

```
type RemoveIndexSignature<T, P = PropertyKey> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends P ? K : never]: T[K];
};

type Result = RemoveIndexSignature<{[x: PropertyKey]: any}, string>;
//   ^? type Result = { [x: string]: any; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Behemoth. Can we say the distributive behaviour does not apply to `extends` when it's in a key remapping clause?

Comment: Yes, the conditional is not distributed on each type in `K` but `K` is seen as one union type if that is what you mean.

Comment: Just to clarify - did you mean `P` (`PropertyKey`) instead of `K`?

Answer (score 0):

`RemoveIndexSignature` is even stranger than it looks.

It appears as if TypeScript is inferring `P` to be something other than `PropertyKey`, which we can see if we replace `P` with `PropertyKey`:

```
// Works
type RemoveIndexSignature<T, P=PropertyKey> = {
    [K in keyof T as (P extends K ? never : (K extends P ? K : never))]: T[K]
};

// Broken
type RemoveIndexSignature2<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as (PropertyKey extends K ? never : (K extends PropertyKey ? K : never))]: T[K]
};

// Test
type Anything = { [k:string]: any, xx: any };
type Good = RemoveIndexSignature<Anything>; // { xx: any; }
type Bad = RemoveIndexSignature2<Anything>; // { [x: string]: any; xx: any; }
```

But let's try one more thing:

```
type Good2 = RemoveIndexSignature<Anything, PropertyKey>; // { x: any; }
```

Clearly `P` is different than `PropertyKey` even if `P=PropertyKey`! I suspected it could be relying a bug in compiler, but then I thought: what if `RemoveIndexSignature<T, PropertyKey>` actually means `RemoveIndexSignature<T, string> | RemoveIndexSignature<T, symbol> | RemoveIndexSignature<T, number>`? Then the contents would be expanded three times, with a different analysis in each one! So I think that's what's happening. Or is it?

Let's try one more thing:

```
// Broken
type Remove3<T, P=PropertyKey> = {
    [K in keyof T as (K extends P ? K : never)]: T[K]
}

type Anything = { [k:string]: any, x: any };
// SEEMS IMPORTANT: TypeScript describes this type in a tooltip as 
// { [k: string]: any; [k: symbol]: any; x: any; }
type ANYthing = { [k:string|symbol]: any, xx: any };

type Bad2 = Remove3<Anything>; // Bad2=Anything; index signature not removed
type Bad3 = Remove3<ANYthing>; // Bad3=ANYthing; index signature not removed
```

If `Remove3<T, P=PropertyKey>` is expanded to `Remove3<T, string> | Remove3<T, symbol> | Remove3<T, number>`, it should work, right? It doesn't work, which seems to falsify the hypothesis. Or does it?

```
// [x: string]: any; is removed as expected, leaving 
// behind { [x: symbol]: any; xx: any; }
type SanityCheck = RemoveIndexSignature3<ANYthing, string>;
```

Now that I think about it, if Remove3 expands to `Remove3<ANYthing, string> | Remove3<ANYthing, symbol> | Remove3<ANYthing, number>`, each of the three branches can remove one index signature, but would leave behind the others, so the expanded version *should* still have them all!

What about the original `RemoveIndexSignature`?

```
// Broken into separate steps to check whether that's equivalent (it is!)
type Step1 = RemoveIndexSignature<ANYthing, string>; // { xx: any }
type Step2 = RemoveIndexSignature<ANYthing, symbol>; // { }
type Step3 = Step1 | Step2;
```

Let's look at this very carefully:

- For `[k: symbol]: any`,

  - `Step1` checks if `P=string` extends `k:symbol` (it does not), then whether `k:symbol` extends `P=string` (again no), so `[k: symbol]: any;` is excluded.
  - `Step2` checks if `P=symbol` extends `k:symbol`. It does, so `[k: symbol]: any;` is excluded.
- For `[k: string]: any;`,

  - `Step1` checks if `P=string` extends `k:string`. It does, so `[k: string]: any` is excluded.
  - `Step2` checks if `P=symbol` extends `k:string` (it does not) and then if `k:string` extends `P=symbol` (again no) so `[k: string]: any` is excluded.
- For `xx: any`,

  - `Step1` checks if `P=string` extends `'xx'` (it does not) and then if `'xx'` extends `P=string` (it does), so `xx: any` is **included**.
  - `Step2` checks if `P=symbol` extends `'xx'` (it does not) and then if `'xx'` extends `P=symbol` (again no) so `xx: any` is excluded.

In conclusion,

- `RemoveIndexSignature<T,U>` does not remove index signatures of type U; **it keeps non-index signatures of type U**.
- When you use `RemoveIndexSignature<T>`, the first check `P extends K` does not check whether `K` extends `PropertyKey` but rather whether it extends `string`, OR extends `symbol`, OR extends `number` in three *separate* tests, thus removing all index signatures.
- It is written this way because the more straightforward definition is illegal:

  ```
  // Syntactically invalid, because there is no || operator for types, 
  // and also because `X extends Y ? A : B` is a quaternary operator.
  type RemoveIndexSignature<T> = {
      [K in keyof T as (
          K extends string || K extends symbol || K extends number 
          ? never : K)]: T[K]
  };
  ```